# Encriptar contraseña con password_hash utilizando conexión PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo, insert, encriptación

estoy tratando de cifrar mi contraseña con password_hash en la base de datos con mysql pero lo he intententado de varias maneras y la verdad no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo. Soy nueva en php y estoy creando un formulario de registro, he leído ya varias páginas y no he encontrado la solución, de lo que si me he dado cuenta es que conectan la bd de otra manera y no sé si esa sea la razón. Aquí está mi código espero me puedan ayudar.

```
ESTA ES MI CONEXIÓN A LA BD SE LLAMA conexión.php
host='localhost';
$dbname='onlineandroid';
$username='root';
$password='password';

try {
$GLOBALS ['pdo'] = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
$GLOBALS ['pdo']->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

function insertar($query, $parametros){
    $stmt = $GLOBALS['pdo']->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($parametros);
    return $stmt->rowCount();

}
?>


ESTA ES MI CLASE USUARIO CONTROLER QUE TIENE EL METODO DE REGISTRO
function registrar($usuario){
    include("app/modelo/conexion.php");
    $nombre_user = ($_POST['nombre_user']);
    $correo = ($_POST['correo']);
    $codigo_acceso = ($_POST['codigo_acceso']);
    $contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];
    $contrasena_hash = password_hash($contrasena, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

 $query = 'INSERT INTO app_paciente VALUES(:id, :nombre_user, :nombre_comp, :contrasena_hash, :telefono, :correo, :codigo_acceso)';

        $valores = array(
            ':id' => null,
            ':nombre_user' => $usuario['nombre_user'],
            ':nombre_comp' => $usuario['nombre_comp'],
            ':contrasena' => $usuario['contrasena_hash'],
            ':telefono' =>$usuario['telefono'],
            ':correo' => $usuario['correo'],
            ':codigo_acceso' => $usuario['codigo_acceso']
            );

           insertar($query, $valores);
    }
```

En mi clase Registro.php en la parte de arriba es donde hago el llamado por POST para realizar el registro con mi formulario

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['nombre_user'])){
    include("app/controlador/usuario_controller.php");

    if(registrar($_POST)){
         $mensaje2 = "<script> alert('Se registró con éxito.');</script>";
    }else{
        $mensaje2 = "<script> alert('Hubo un problema, intente más tarde.');</script>";
    }
  }

?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoIntegrador\app\modelo\conexion.php:25 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoIntegrador\app\modelo\conexion.php(25): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoIntegrador\app\controlador\usuario_controller.php(95): insertar('INSERT INTO app...', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoIntegrador\Registrar.php(6): registrar(Array) #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoIntegrador\app\modelo\conexion.php on line 25

Comment: Este erros es el que me sale

Answer (score 0):

Sobre la forma de conexión. Hay gente que usa mysqli y otros (como tú y yo) usamos PDO. PDO tiene por defecto cuidado con el SQL injection y esas cosas. Cuando busques algo recuerda añadir "pdo" para que se acerque a lo que estás haciendo.

Sobre tu código, a no ser que estés usando una versión muy antigua de PHP debería funcionar. Ahora bien, en la sentencia SQL veo que no pones el nombre de las tablas. Si tienes más columnas en esa tabla o el orden no es ése puede haber errores. Algo así. Ten en cuenta que las tablas me las imagino según tu código, puede que no sean esas:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO app_paciente (id, nombre_user, nombre_comp, contrasena_hash, telefono, codigo_acceso) VALUES(:id, :nombre_user, :nombre_comp, :contrasena_hash, :telefono, :correo, :codigo_acceso)';
```

También, para depurar el error, pon un:

```
var_dump($password_hash);
```

antes de hacer el insertar para confirmar que eso no te devuelve false y que está funcionando.

Luego después del insertar, pdo tiene una función que es LastInsertId() que devuelve el ID del último row añadido, si no funcionó te da un error. Así podrás investigar más por donde viene el problema.